# Is possible cast as Date with format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S'?

Tags: hive

I have one table with two columns, `id` (string) and `myTs` (bigint).

I want to create a View with this two columns, but `myTs` must be date type:

```
CREATE myView AS SELECT id, myToDate(myTs) FROM myTable;
```

`myTs` is a timestamp, I want to transform it into a date with timezone Europe/Madrid and format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S`.
For example, with `myTs = 1167529028000`, if I execute:

```
from_utc_timestamp(myTs, 'Europe/Madrid') 
--Result: '2006-12-31 02:37:08.0'
```

I get the correct result but the type is timestamp, If I try cast it to date I lost the format:

```
cast(from_utc_timestamp(myTs, 'Europe/Madrid') as date) 
--Result: '2006-12-31'
```

Another option:

```
date_format(from_utc_timestamp(myTs, 'Europe/Madrid'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S') 
--Result: '2006-12-31 02:37:08.0'
```

The result is String, if I cast as Date, again removes the format:

```
cast(date_format(from_utc_timestamp(myTs, 'Europe/Madrid'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S') as Date) 
--Result: '2006-12-31'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You explained your question pretty well. But unfortunately, it's not possible. If you define any field as date, it is simply a date. The moment you add hours, mins, secs - any of them, you have to define them as a timestamp. Date format will simply have year month and the day.